# Why rename simply doesn't work?

Tags: rename

I need to rename multiple files, and some tutorials shows that the command `rename` is the best option instead of just use `mv` for each file.

But then I have these files:

```
 ReconhecimentoImagens2021-10-18--2020-2.mp4       ReconhecimentoImagens2021-11-01--2020-2.mp4   ReconhecimentoImagens2021-11-22--2020-2.mp4
 ReconhecimentoImagens2021-10-25--2020-2.mp4       ReconhecimentoImagens2021-11-08--2020-2.mp4   ReconhecimentoImagens2021-11-24--2020-2.mp4
'ReconhecimentoImagens2021-11-01--2020-2(2).mp4'   ReconhecimentoImagens2021-11-17--2020-2.mp4   ReconhecimentoImagens2021-11-29--2020-2.mp4
```

and just for a test I tried this command:

```
rename 's/2021/ /' *.mp4
```

and NOTHING happens, I get code 4 that according to the man page means 'nothing was renamed'.

I searched for multiple tutorials and nobody seems to be doing anything different than that so, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There are several versions of the `rename` command. Could you state yours?

Comment: Are you using the perl version of rename (AKA `prename`, `perl-rename`, `file-rename`)? or some other rename (like the one in the `util-linux` package)?   Find out by running `rename -V` - if it mentions perl or File::Rename at all (e.g. `/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 1.30, File::Rename::Options version 1.10`) then it's the perl rename.  If not, then it isn't - and has completely different capabilities and options.   If you're using some other rename, I recommend installing and using the perl rename (e.g. on Debian and related distros `sudo apt-get install rename`).

Comment: On other distros, the package might be named `prename` or `file-rename` or similar.

Comment: its `rename util-linux 2.37.2` @cas @FelixJN

Comment: util-linux's rename is a completely different program with completely different and incompatible options and capabilities.  Either read `man rename` to figure out how to use it (it won't be *anything* like `rename 's/2021/ /' *.mp4`) or (highly recommended) install the perl rename utility.

Comment: The command is fine and it should work. All '2021' in the file names should become spaces.
Make sure there is no directory mixup. - that is a most likely reason.
Make sure that you have write permission and can change file names - just try mv on one file.
Make sure that "2021" you see in the file names are actually numbers "2021" and not some unicode equivalents. - possible, but rare.

Comment: BTW, when you do install perl rename, you probably want to run something more like `rename 's/--2020//' *.mp4`, otherwise you'll just be replacing 2020 with a space in matching filenames resulting in filenames like `ReconhecimentoImagens2021-10-18-- -2.mp4` instead of `ReconhecimentoImagens2021-10-18-2.mp4`.  You may even want `'s/--2020//; s/2021/-2021/'` to also add a `-` before the 2021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's different versions of rename, and yours isn't the one with PERL regex support.

For most Linux distros and other unixoid systems, there's some package that contains the `rename.pl` or simply `rename` command that's built from perl.

In your use case, the "classical" util-linux `rename` fully suffices:

```
rename "2021" " "  *.mp4
```

would do.

Honestly, my shell does well enough that I don't have to remember all these fine things. I learned `sed` somewhat OK-ish once, I've learned my shell's `for` syntax once, and that's it:

```bsh
for filename in *.mp4 ; do
  mv "${filename}" "$(echo "${filename}" | sed 's/regex/replacement/')"
done
```

is pretty easy to remember for me, at least, and should work in bash and zsh and other bourne-alike shells. Not an extra command I have to learn.

In fact, if you want things to be simple, you can use your own favourite shell's variable expansion to its fullest extent:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
if [[ "${#}" -lt 2 ]] ; then 
  echo "Usage: ${0} [-r] PATTERN REPLACEMENT [FILE...]"
  echo "Uses normal Zsh globbing for pattern, unless -r is specified:"
  echo "In that case, use the regexp-replace loadable ZSH function"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ "${1}" = "-r" ]]; then
  autoload regexp-replace
  REGEX=1
  shift 1
else
  set -o extendedglob
  REGEX=0
fi

PATTERN="${1}"
REPLACEMENT="${2}"
shift 2

if [[ "${REGEX}" -eq 0 ]]; then
  for filename in ${argv} ; do
    mv "${filename}" "${filename/${1}/${2}}" || echo "Problem renaming ${filename}" >&2
  done
else
  for filename in ${argv} ; do
    original_filename="${filename}
    regexp_replace filename "${PATTERN}" "${REPLACEMENT}"
    mv "${original_filename} "${filename}" || echo "Problem renaming ${original_filename}" >&2
  done
fi
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. I used sed like this before, but I was looking for something easier to understand in a fast read, but thanks either way, it helped.